# I have an error in my procedure MySQL (IF/ELSEIF/THEN)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I'm trying to make a procedure for the membership program.
But, it seems that I did something wrong.

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE calcul_membership(IN par_id_customer INT, OUT par_membership VARCHAR(50))
>
> BEGIN
> SELECT COUNT(booking.id_booking) count from customer
> INNER JOIN booking ON customer.id_customer=booking.id_customer
> GROUP BY customer.id_customer
>
>
> IF count >= 5 AND count < 10 THEN
>   SET par_membership = 'Silver';
> ELSE IF count >= 10 AND count < 30 THEN 
>      SET par_membership='Gold';
> ELSE IF count >= 30 THEN 
>      SET par_membership='Platinum';
> ELSE SET par_membership= 'Novice';
>
> END IF;
>
>
> END ;
> ```

I don't know what to do...
Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: ELSEIF not ELSE IF - you got it write in the title but not the code? Also you may have to set delimiters AND select count() into @count or a declared variable. And if your select returns more than 1 row you have a problem since you cannot stuff a resultset into a variable.

Comment: It may syntax but it doesn't work you need to test par_id_customer  in the select